# hasMany não funciona corretamente

Tags: laravel

boa noite!! estou tentando lançar relacão de dados(grupos e redes) mas não funciona...o model do grupos está assim:

```
function Redes(){
     return $this->hasMany('App\rede','grupo_id','id');
}
```

no model de rede está assim:

```
class rede extends Model
{
  protected $table = "redes";
}
```

estou tentando exibir os dados assim:

function Index(grupos $grupos,rede $rede){

```
    $lista = $grupos->all();
    foreach($lista as $li):

        foreach($li->Redes() as $d):
            print_r($d->id);
       endforeach;

    endforeach;
}
```

e nada, o que está errado??
Obrigado pela constante atenção!!!

Comment: Não seria apenas `$li->Redes`?

Comment: Anderson...verdade!! eu sempre me esqueço...cara, muito obrigado!!! valeu mesmo!!!!!